# z-index transition delay not working?

Tags: html, css

I have created 2 divs of same size. 1st div has z-index=1 and color red. 2nd div has z-index=0 and color yellow. I want that on hovering over the divs, the z-index of yellow box(which was below initially) should become 2 (so that it comes up) after 2 seconds. But I cant understand why the code is not working.

```css
#animate1,
#animate2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#animate1 {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

#animate2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: z-index 0 linear 2s;
}

#all:hover #animate2 {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="all">
      <div id="animate1">
      </div>
      <div id="animate2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is it not doing that you expect? check out http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/gboJf

Answer (score 0):

You should update `#animate2` style from `transition: z-index 0 linear 2s;` to `transition: z-index cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1) 2s;`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `visibility:hidden`; and `opacity:0;` then on hover change them to `visibility:visible;` and  `opacity:1` instead of changing `z-index;`

```css
#animate1,
#animate2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#animate1 {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

#animate2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:2;
  transition: all linear 2s;
}

#all:hover #animate2 {
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="all">
      <div id="animate1">
      </div>
      <div id="animate2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete de '0' or put '0s' in `transition: z-index 0 linear 2s;`

```css
#animate1,
#animate2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#animate1 {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

#animate2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: z-index linear 2s;
}

#all:hover #animate2 {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="all">
      <div id="animate1">
      </div>
      <div id="animate2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`transition-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition-duration) you have set does not include a unit - [<time>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/time) data types in CSS *must* include a unit or they are considered invalid and, therefore, ignored. In the instance of the example code you included, as you are using the `transition` shorthand property then the whole lot is actually being ignored.

So, to fix your issue, you need to add a unit to the `transition-duration` -  either `s` or `ms` will do as the value is `0` - or, as others have suggested, because the value is `0`, simply omit the `transition-duration` completely.